# QML and C++ : How to pass a reference of an exported C++ object to an exported C++ class?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I exported a `C++` class and object like so:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/QQuickViewExample/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    //object export
    ClassA classA(QString stuff);
    QQmlContext* context = viewer.engine()->rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty("_classA", &classA);

    //class export
    qmlRegisterType<ClassB>("CustomComponents", 1, 0, "ClassB");


    return app.exec();
}
```

I will create an arbitrary number of `QML` objects with `ClassB` embedded inside. I want every `ClassB` to have a reference or pointer to the 1 `ClassA` that exists in this program. How can I, in `QML`, grab a reference of `ClassA` when I am initializing `ClassB` in my `QML` objects, so that `ClassB` can use `ClassA`?

Comment: You have to change the order of actions: 1) register B 2) set A instance on the root context C) load the source; in the source, you instantiate B { aPtr: _classA }. That's all of it :)

Comment: This fixed it! I will give you the correct answer if you turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: You are welcome :) G'luck with them QMLs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the order of actions:

1. register B
2. set A instance on the root context
3. load the source, where you instantiate (as many times as you need):

   `B { aPtr: _classA }`

The rationale is:

- for smth to appear in QML sources and be used to instantiate classes, those classes have to be registered first (a C++ QML plugin could do that too)
- if items are relying on existence of a context property, they should be created only after the context property has been set

Given that, steps (1) and (2) above can actually be swapped.

There are ways to create, parent and wire everything by hand from C++, I believe, but that would be an example of extremely dark art (think creating bindings manually from JS expressions, creating a context, then instantiating items into it...); never seen that in the wild :)

Comment: Would it be possible to define aPtr as const inside of ClassB? I tried doing so but I got build errors. I would like a const pointer of ClassA inside of ClassB, so ClassB doesn't muddle anything up!

Comment: @trianta2 If a singleton instance of ClassA is created first for that purpose, yes, I think.